# NSTableView notification after reload

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Is there any notification from NSTableView that will alert me after the table has finished loading data after a [table reloadData] ? I want to scroll to the last row after the data has been loaded with  [table scrollRowToVisible:lastRowIndex], but the table needs to be loaded for it to work.

Update:
After adding new items to the table, I want to scroll to the very last one, so its visible.
Also I want to to this when the view is loaded and displayed.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think NSTableView supports this directly.  Could you add some details about when and why you want the scrolling to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could just subclass NSTableView’s -reloadData method, but I’d caution you that it might get called more often than you’d like.